# How to capture Logitech trackman special buttons using Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am using Trackman marble mouse from logitech.
http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/trackman-marble

This is a great mouse but lacks scrolling wheel. In spite of that, it's pretty good mouse.

I want to capture special buttons on this mouse.

Following works for all other mice but not ror Trackman... 
;Not really helping with TrackMan Marble.

XButton1::WheelDown

XButton2::WheelUp

I tried to capture mouseclick for special button which using "Key  History and Script Info" but that doesn't give anything..

Is there anything else left to do?

Thanks

Pravin

Answer (score 1):

```
$XButton1::
    Loop {
        if not GetKeyState("XButton1", "P") {
            break
        }
        Send {WheelDown}
        Sleep, 100
    }
return

$XButton2::
    Loop {
        if not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P") {
            break
        }
        Send {WheelUp}
        Sleep, 100
    }
return
```

Tested and works for me under Windows 10 now. Been using this on Windows 7 and 8 as well.

You might want to modify the sleep milliseconds time to suit your taste.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu, you can create or open /usr/share/X11/50-marblemouse.conf then fill in with the following config:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier      "Marble Mouse"
MatchProduct    "Logitech USB Trackball"
MatchIsPointer  "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver          "evdev"
Option          "SendCoreEvents" "true"

#  Physical buttons come from the mouse as:
#     Big:   1 3
#     Small: 8 9
#
# This makes left small button (8) into the middle, and puts
#  scrolling on the right small button (9).
#
# comment as hand not comfort
#Option "Buttons"            "9"
#Option "ButtonMapping"      "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9"
#Option "EmulateWheel"       "true"
#Option "EmulateWheelButton" "9"
# reverse above small buttons(not as expected)
Option "Buttons"            "8"
Option "ButtonMapping"      "1 9 3 4 5 6 7 2 8"
Option "EmulateWheel"       "true"
Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"

Option "YAxisMapping"       "4 5"
Option "XAxisMapping"       "6 7"


# left hand
#Option "Buttons"            "9"
#Option "ButtonMapping"      "3 8 1 4 5 6 7 2 9"
#Option "EmulateWheel"       "true"
#Option "EmulateWheelButton" "9"

#Option "YAxisMapping"       "4 5"
#Option "XAxisMapping"       "6 7"
EndSection
```

For more detail, you can refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB